# DecimalFormat no me muestra el 0 en los decimales

Tags: java

Tengo esto:

```
public String refrescarPrecio(double cantidad)
{
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance();
    df.applyPattern("$ ###,###.##");

    String str = "";
    str = df.format(cantidad);

    return str;
}
```

Si el calculo que hace mi programa debe mostrar "0.30", solo muestra "0.3".

¿Cómo podría arreglarlo? Intenté reemplazando los "#" por "0" pero no funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si cambio `"$ ###,###.##"` por `"$ ###,##0.00"`, me funciona muy bien.

```
public String refrescarPrecio(double cantidad)
{
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance();
    df.applyPattern("$ ###,##0.00");

    return df.format(cantidad);
}
```

[Demostración](http://rextester.com/RMX89255).

Answer (score 0):

Esto te podría servir

```
double n = 651.5176515121351;

n = Math.round(n * 100);
n = n/100;
```

Edit 1:

```
cantidad = roundTwoDecimals(cantidad);

public double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

Comment: Hola, el problema es que uso decimalformat para poder mostrarlo de una forma bonita, no veo forma de aplicar esto al metodo de decilamformat :(

Comment: @RobertGomez lo modifique, ahora si use decimalFormat

Comment: Hola, gracias por tratar de ayudarme, no me ha funcionado. Tengo esto:
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
  
  String str = "";
  str = Double.toString(Double.valueOf(df.format(cantidad)));
  
  return str;
qué tengo mal?.

Answer (score -1):

¿Como estas imprimiendo? si solo quieres imprimir el resultado podrias usar lo siguiente:

```
 System.out.printf("%.2f",variable); #Imprime con 2 decimales
```

Ojala este enlace te sirva: http://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_standard_edition/%C2%BFque_formato_usar_para_2_decimales_o_ninguno

Comment: Hola, para imprimir uso esto: txtPrecioTotal.setText(refrescarPrecio(callcenter.getTotalFacturado()));, le asigno el valor a un textfield, que puedo hacer en este caso?. Como podria arreglarlo?